# How to Check two csv/xml files are same or not in java

Tags: java, xml, spring, csv, compare

My Requirement

To check whether two csv/xml are same or not and I don't need differences.

No need to scan whole content and capture differences between two files. Just API has to return, once it finds first difference.

Please suggest me the best way for above.

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the md5 to check if both have the same content

```
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            InputStream file1 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/Documents/hello.txt"));
            InputStream file2 = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/Documents/hello2.txt"));    

            String md5_file1 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(file1);
            String md5_file2 = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(file2);

            if(md5_file1.equals(md5_file2)){
                System.out.println("Same file");
            }else{
                System.out.println("It's not the same file");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `@SpringBootApplication` for this? :)

Comment: Good spot! I forgot to delete the annotation : ) Editing the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for *equality* or literally if they are one and the same? There's a big difference!

In most cases, being the same can be determined by comparing creation time, modification time, name and exact file size.

In case of equality, just strip the times from the comparison.

Comment: Need to check content